# Convert Shadertoy Shader to glsl webgl

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader, webgl, shadertoy

I need to convert this shadertoy shader to glsl , besically it turn-off the texture anti-aliasing, it is manual  nearest neighbor filter

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    ivec2 sz = textureSize(iChannel0, 0);
    uv = (vec2(0.5) + vec2(ivec2(uv * vec2(sz)))) / vec2(sz);
    vec3 col = texture(iChannel0, uv).rgb;

    // Output to screen
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
}
```

I know
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord ) **becomes** void main( )

and fragCoord **becomes** gl_FragCoord **and** fragColor **becomes** gl_FragColor

I also mentioned **uniform sampler2D media;**  so texture(iChannel0, uv).rgb; **becomes** texture2D(media, uv).rgb;

**But how i convert these 2 lines to glsl**

```
 ivec2 sz = textureSize(iChannel0, 0);
 uv = (vec2(0.5) + vec2(ivec2(uv * vec2(sz)))) / vec2(sz);
```

i mean what is ivec2 and textureSize is in glsl and how i can convert this  **ivec2 sz = textureSize(iChannel0, 0);**  to glsl ?

Comment: `textureSize` is a GLSL function, nothing to port there.

Comment: @AKX However it does'n exist in OpenGL (ES) Shading Language 1.00: https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf / https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.20.pdf

Comment: I hope there is more to this than reinventing [`image-rendering: pixelated;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by changing the texture parameter TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER to NEAREST.

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```

And optionally add

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```

Find more info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texParameter